# (node:32604) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: message.guild.channels.delete is not a function

Tags: discord.js

So I am trying to setup an event that creates a channel when someone reacts to the message, and deletes it when they unreact to it. Here is the code

```
module.exports = {
name: 'ticket',
description: "Sets up a reaction role message!",
async execute(message, args, Discord, client) {

    const channel = '799546836327202877'
    const TicketMade = ''

    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#e42643')
    .setTitle('React with the icon below to open a ticket!')

let messageEmbed = await message.channel.send(embed);
messageEmbed.react(TicketMade);

client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
    if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
    if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
    if (user.bot) return;
    if (!reaction.message.guild) return;



    message.guild.channels
      .create('ticket', {
        type: 'text',
      })
      .then((channel) => {
        const categoryId = '800219980561776680'
        channel.setParent(categoryId)
      })
  })


client.on('messageReactionRemove', async (reaction, user) => {
    if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
    if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
    if (user.bot) return;
    if (!reaction.message.guild) return;

    message.guild.channels
      .delete('ticket')




    })
}
```

The error I get when I try to unreact is: (node:32604) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: message.guild.channels.delete is not a function. I've looked all over for how to fix it but I couldn't find any solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The simple reasoning for your issue is that `.delete()` while talking about channels is `Channel Object` based. Meaning you'll first have to find/get the channel you're looking for using its name/ID, turn it into an object, and then you could use the `.delete()` function, this can be done as the following:

```
client.on('messageReactionRemove', async (reaction, user) => {
  if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
  if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
  if (user.bot) return;
  if (!reaction.message.guild) return;
  /*
  const channel = await message.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === 'ticket');
  */
  const channel = await message.guild.channels.cache.get('channel id here')
  channel.delete();
})
```

Comment: Is there anyway to get the id automatically since the id will be changed every time a new channel is made

Comment: That would require someplace to store all of your ID's, in which most cases would require a database. My suggestion is to instead name your tickets `ticket-${message.author.username}` so then while using the `.find()` function you can easily get the channel object with the reactor's name.

Comment: So the error has change from it's not a function to it saying that it is not defined. ```UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'delete' of undefined```